# Undo changes of ngModel doesn't reflect the results in the view

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table of items and the table cells are inline editable. I want to implement a feature to undo changes to each cell, so I made a copy of each object of the array at the begining.

```
this.mapedArr = this.arr.map(i => {
  i.oldValues = Object.assign({}, i);
  return i;
})
```

Then after clicking cancel, I copy the old values instead of the new values.

```
cancel(i) {  
   i = Object.assign({}, i.oldValues);
}
```

If you check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5yupw9), where I tryied to implement a small example of what I have, you can see in the console that the values change back to the old values but don't reflect the results in the view. Where is the problem?

Comment: Behaviour is because of ngModel.Update the value which is inside array which you are looping then it will update the model

Comment: please check the updated answer- contains link to stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the element in the array which you are looping it will work

Please find updated stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb6em6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the item you pass to the `cancel` function **has different reference** than the one in your `temp`.

What you could come up with is something like:

```
  cancel(item) {
    const {name, city} = item.oldValues; 
    this.mapedArr[this.mapedArr.indexOf(item)] = {...this.mapedArr[this.mapedArr.indexOf(item)], name, city} 
  }
```

[Here's an update version of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggplsm)

Comment: This's working too, but I have a lot of properties in each object, not only name and city.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the `object.assign` since you are putting the name into another property call `oldValue`

```
  constructor() {
    this.mapedArr = this.arr.map(i => {
      i.oldValues = i.name
      return i;
    })
    console.log('this.mapedArr ', this.mapedArr);
  }

  cancel(i) {
    console.log('i new', i);
    i.name =  i.oldValues 
    console.log('i old', i);
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i7vnbr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: doesn't answer the intended problem. Model needs to be updated

Comment: model updating since the object keep a reference to arr

Comment: not sure what u are saying. when you change the value and click cancel, changes should revert back and original value should appear.

Comment: This solution is working in the stackblitz, but I don't know why it didn't work in my real code!

Comment: create your own stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

your component:

```
  constructor() {
     this.mapedArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.arr));
     console.log('this.mapedArr ', this.mapedArr);
  }

 cancel(i) {
     this.mapedArr[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.arr[i]));
 }
```

your html:

```
<p *ngFor="let i of mapedArr; let ind = index">
   Name: {{i.name }}<br>
   City: {{ i.city }}<br>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='i.name' /><br>
   <button (click)='cancel(ind)'>Cancel</button>
<br>
<br>
</p>
```